# How can I use cache tags whith a mocked Cache in phpunit tests?

Tags: laravel, caching, mocking, phpunit

I have implemented Cache tags on a laravel project and I have something like this in my controller :

```
if (Cache::tags(['api'])->has('someKey')) {
    return new JsonResponse(Cache::tags(['api'])->get('someKey'));
}
```

I would like to write a phpunit test to test this code : I mocked the Cache like found in the laravel documentation, but I haven't found anything on how to use `tags` on a mocked cache

I tried :

```
Cache::tags(['api'])->shouldReceive('has')->with('someKey')->andReturn(true)->once();
```

or

```
Cache::shouldReceive('has')->tags(['api'])->with('someKey')->andReturn(true)->once();
```

But none of this works, I got `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Cache\ArrayStore::shouldReceive()` or
`call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Mockery\Expectation' does not have a method 'tags'`

Does anybody have a clue ? thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to mock tags call by itself and use `->andReturnSelf()` to be able to make the mock chain. So calling `Cache::tags(['api'])` returns the mock instance.

```
Cache::shouldReceive('tags')->with(['api'])->andReturnSelf();

Cache::shouldReceive('has')->once()->with('someKey')->andReturn(true);
Cache::shouldReceive('get')->once()->with('someKey')->andReturn('result');
```

Comment: Ran it in tinker and it should work, else write a comment and i will gladly help :)